# Get list of Chrome extensions from Chrome app

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome extension that uses the `chrome.management` [API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management) to get a list of installed Chrome extensions and apps. The problem starts because I also want to use the `chrome.syncFileSystem` [API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/syncFileSystem) which only seems to be available to Chrome apps.

If I switch the extension to an app, I can no longer use the `chrome.management` API. I haven't been able to find an API to access the installed extensions from an app. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, not without having both an extension and an app.

Google has a private API to do that, but for public API, they want apps to be as independent as possible from the browser.

Comment: Allowing apps to use `chrome.management` is being considered: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=455550